# Dynamically showing images using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a database with a list of items.  Each item has it's own unique ID.  I would like to associate the ID with an image in a folder using AngularJS.  I have tried this:

```
<img ng-src="~/images/assets/mainImg/{{stages.stageID}}.gif" alt="{{imageDescription}}" style="width:100px;height:100px">
```

But it doesn't work.  Any suggestions please?

Comment: Is your base href set properly in .NET? This is as much a .Net question as an angular question (probably more). Inspect the image in the browser and see what the path is resolving to.

Comment: can you check the error ? what is the path it is actually set when rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a directory called `~` in your public path? You more than likely just want the define the source as below.

`<img ng-src="images/assets/mainImg/{{stages.stageID}}.gif" alt="{{imageDescription}}" style="width:100px;height:100px">`

If this doesn't work can you show us your directory structure?

Comment: Actually, mine does work.  {{stages.stageID}} should've been {{stageID}}. Been coding too long today! Thanks for your correct answer!  If it helps the ~/ refers to the root directory of the project, easier than using many ../